# Use lapply function on imputed datasets (MICE)

Tags: r, lapply, r-mice

I am finding it very difficult to understand how to use lapply on imputed datasets in R.

Here is a code for an example dataset (with 6 Variables: "Ozone", "Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day"):

```
data <- airquality
data[4:10,3] <- rep(NA,7)
data[1:5,4] <- NA

tempData <- mice(data,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
```

After that, let's run a linear regression on the imputed datasets.

```
> reg1
call :
with.mids(data = tempData, expr = lm(Ozone ~ Wind))

call1 :
mice(data = data, m = 5, method = "pmm", maxit = 50, seed = 500)

nmis :
  Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
     37       7       7       5       0       0 

analyses :
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Wind)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Wind  
     92.401       -5.067  
[...]
```

So far, so good.

Now I was wondering if I can use lapply to conduct regression analyses for multiple dependent variables and store them in a list type object. Below, you can see my failed attempt.

```
> variables_subset<-c("Ozone","Solar.R", "Temp")
> models<-lapply(tempData[,variables_subset],
+                function(x) (with(tempData, lm(x ~  Wind))))
Error in tempData[, variables_subset] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Is there a way to make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what exactly you were trying to do but here are few suggestions :

- `tempData` is not a dataframe (`tempData$data` is) so you cannot directly subset it.
- I use `reformulate` here to create formula which is applied in `lm`
- Instead of looping over columns values in `lapply`, I loop over column names which also makes it easy to construct formula.

So try :

```
variables_subset<-c("Ozone","Solar.R", "Temp")
lapply(variables_subset,function(x)  
          lm(reformulate("Wind", x), data = tempData$data))

#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate("Wind", x), data = tempData$data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         Wind  
#     99.166       -5.782  


#[[2]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate("Wind", x), data = tempData$data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         Wind  
#   189.5896      -0.3649  


#[[3]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate("Wind", x), data = tempData$data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         Wind  
#     89.982       -1.142
```

---

To get nested list using imputed datasets you can try :

```
dat <- mice::complete(tempData, "long", inc = TRUE)

model_list <- lapply(split(dat, dat$.imp), function(x) {
                 lapply(variables_subset,function(y)  
                     lm(reformulate("Wind", y), data = x))
               })
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what the problem was. But is there a way to get something like a list within a list? What I want is a list of results for each dependent variable (Ozone, Solar, Temp). Each of these lists should then contain another list (with one entry for each of the five imputed datasets). Sorry for not having been clear enough in my previous post.

Comment: @Saja01 Where are those 5 imputed datasets in `tempData` ?

Comment: tempData contains 5 imputed datasets based on a dataframe with NAs (because I set m  = 5 in the mice function). The results for the complete dataset can later be combined with Rubin's rules for each dependent variable.

Comment: `tempData$data` has only one dataframe.

Comment: I think these are in tempData$imp, not tempData$data. Data is the original dataset with no imputation.

Comment: @Saja01 Ok...I think you can get them using `complete` function. Check updated answer.